# Why are these vectors $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent? (Minkowski Theory)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The context is Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, Chapter V - Minkowski Theory (p. 31).

I'm having trouble w/ the proof of Proposition (5.2) there. Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n$.

We have the map $j\colon K\to K_{\mathbb{R}}$ given by $j(a)=(\tau_{1}(a),\dots, \tau_{n}(a)$),

where $\tau_{1},\dots,\tau_{n}$ are the $n$ complex embeddings $K\to\mathbb{C}$, and $K_{\mathbb{R}}$ is just the $n$-fold product $\prod_{\tau}\mathbb{C}$ with the property that entries indexed by conjugate pairs are conjugate to each other. In particular, entries indexed by real embeddings are real numbers.

He claims that the image of a non-zero ideal $I$ of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ by this map is a complete lattice in $K_{\mathbb{R}}$.

For the proof, he proceeds by taking a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $\{\alpha_{1},\dots,\alpha_{n}\}$ of $I$ and then simply states that 
\begin{equation}
\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}j(\alpha_{1})+\dots+\mathbb{Z}j(\alpha_{n})
\end{equation}
is a complete lattice.

I believe that it is left to the reader to verify that these $j(\alpha_{i})$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

**But are they?**

Clearly they are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent, but this no way implies the above. How to proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the $n\times n$-matrix with complex coefficients, whose $i$-th column is given by $j(\alpha_i)$. From Linear Algebra we know that the columns, i.e. the $j(\alpha_i)$ are linearly independent (over $\mathbb{C}$) if and only if the determinant of $A$ is non-zero. Thus, for proving that the $j(\alpha_i)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore over $\mathbb{R}$, it suffices to prove that $\operatorname{det}(A) \neq 0$.

Since the $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ of $I$ is also a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $K$, the result follows from the non-degeneracy of the trace form $K\times K \to \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yeah, I later realized the discrimant was at play. Thanks.